# How continue processing shell script after respect of condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, while-loop

in my shell script, I am asking a question  and verifying the result with 2 conditions. What is I wanna do is to continue reading the rest of script if these conditions are true otherwise the question must always be asking user.

Other thing, it must be a function because I will use it many times.

And I purposely simplified the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

t="5"

function ask_version {
while true ; do

echo -ne "\033[32m$1\033[0m : "
read -n 1 -r

if [[ ! $REPLY =~ ^[0-9] ]] ; then
  echo -e " Please respect number format"
elif [[ $t -ne $REPLY ]] ; then
  echo -e "It is not the true number"
else
  return 0
fi

done
}

ask_version "Please type a number"
if [[ $? = 0 ]]
#Here I wanna do the test, if true I continue...
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im not wrong it seems that you need something like this:

While your conditions is not respected repeat the function and ask to type a number. When all conditions are met break and exit the script.

```
 while true; do
    ask_version "Please type a number"
    if (( $? == 0 )); then 
      #continue with the script
      #if all conditions are ok
      echo "Exiting"
      break
    else
      #something wrong
    fi
  done
```

Comment: No, when conditions met continue to execute the rest of script !!

Comment: Yes. If all condition are met continue the rest of the script and then, at the end you will exit from the loop.
Otherwise re-ask for a number in loop.

Comment: I didn't want to insert all my code in a if-statement. So I inverse the if condition. Thank you